# Get the column date type in Vertica database

Tags: vertica

when i used PROJECTION_COLUMNS get column type
it spent too much time.
is there have another table or function to search column type?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few other column system tables (i.e. [`v_catalog.columns`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/COLUMNS.htm)). You can alternatively use [`EXPORT_TABLES`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/EXPORT_TABLES.htm) to generate a SQL script of the DDL for the table:

```
=> SELECT EXPORT_TABLES(' ','store.store_orders_fact');
```

Comment: Thanks, EXPORT_TABLES(' ','store.store_orders_fact') can be right.           But in system table I can't find PRIMARY KEY information.                           Anyway  thanks very much.

Comment: @Sanborn Have you tried [searching the documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/PRIMARY_KEYS.htm)?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get a view of your keys just use the V_CATALOG.TABLE_CONSTRIANTS table. 
[Link to the oficial doc](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.htm)

Here is query that might help you:

```
select * from table_constraints where table_name='bla bla';
```

Take a look over the table documentation so you can understand what the columns represent.